# How cleanup civicrm database

Tags: activities, database, cache

I've got a civicrm database of 1.4 Go (information available in PhpMyAdmin)
1Go is used by civicrm_activity table
I would like to know if have to clean, purge the database to reduce its size, cache or others maintenance actions.

I find some actions on documentation for cache files but nothing about database

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 2):

`civicrm_activity` is a legitimate table with legitimate data.  You can use the API to mass-delete activities - but only you (and/or your users) can determine what represents data that is reasonable to delete.

If it's that large, I suspect it's quite likely that you're sending frequent mailings to large groups of people - the mailing history might be reasonable thing to delete.

Comment: Do you know if deleting old mailings will remove the activities too? We've got a bad case of this with a few clients. For one, civicrm_activities is 3G. (Also would be nice to have a gui to batch delete/archive mailings but that's for a different convo).

Comment: @herb Doing `SHOW CREATE TABLE civicrm_mailing` doesn't reveal any foreign keys - so it would have to happen at the PHP level if it happens.  And frankly, I doubt it; I know deleting a Contribution Batch doesn't delete the associated activity (with disastrous results).  I think someone wrote an archiver though - if you grab me on Mattermost I can tell you who to talk to.